# Sorting a dictionary by value then key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I can sort by key or value, but I need it sorted by value, then key, in one line. To explain this better I can show you my problem:

```
dict = {'apple': 2, 'banana': 3, 'almond':2 , 'beetroot': 3, 'peach': 4}
```

I want my output to be sorted descending by their value and then ascending (A-Z) by their key (alphabetically). Resulting in such a list:

With the output of:   `['peach', 'banana', 'beetroot', 'almond', 'apple']`

The only way I know how to do it so far is:

```
[v[0] for v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda(k,v): (v,k))]
```

With the output of:   `['almond', 'apple', 'banana', 'beetroot', 'peach']`

So it has sorted the values in ascending order and the keys alphabetically in ascending order (A-Z). So if I reverse this:

```
[v[0] for v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda(k,v): (v,k), reverse=True)]
```

With the output of:   `['peach', 'beetroot', 'banana', 'apple', 'almond']`

It has sorted the values in descending order and the keys alphabetically in descending order (Z-A).

Is there a way I can sort the values in descending order and the keys in ascending order (i.e. A-Z) and get the output I showed above?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to take advantage of the fact that the values are numbers.

```
>>> [v[0] for v in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k))]
['peach', 'banana', 'beetroot', 'almond', 'apple']
```

Comment: Just a reminder that Python 3 removed tuple parameter unpacking, so the line above should now be written as `[v[0] for v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0]))]`. See PEP 3113 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Comment: The key function could also be written as `operator.itemgetter(1, 0)` *if* you don't have to reverse the ordering of one of key/value.

Comment: What does key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k)) mean? I understand lambda is an anonymous function but  the fact that it doesnt have a return statement is confusing.

Comment: @NickKiermaier: The expression *is* what is returned.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: @GuiAmbros, `lambda kv: (-kv[1]...` is awful. No other syntax support in 3?

Answer (score 6):

To sort by descending value is, for negatable quantities, to sort by ascending negative-of-value.

```
[v[0] for v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda(k,v): (-v,k))]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = {'apple':2, 'banana':3, 'almond':2, 'beetroot':3, 'peach':4}
>>> [k for k, v in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k))]
['peach', 'banana', 'beetroot', 'almond', 'apple']
```