# Counting digit Frequencies with Python

Tags: dictionary

I need your help in Python 2.7.

I made a dictionary:

```
{'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 5, '6': 5}
```

**Question 1:**
What can I do if I want to print the key that has the highest value?

**Question 2 :**
In this case,  '2' and '6' have both the same high value,
so I want Python to print the digit (type: int) of the highest key only (6).
How can I program this?

I tried many times and failed...
Im looking for easier way..without using 'sort'

Comment: What did you try? What did you get? What did you expect instead?

Comment: Can you put the code that you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a dictionary by value then key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919342/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-key)

Answer (score 0):

*simple pythonic code*

```
a = {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 5, '6': 5}
m = sorted(a.items(),key=lambda x :x[1])
d = [i[0] for i in m if i[1]==m[-1][1]]
print d
print m[-1][0]
```