# What does -x mean in the key of sorted function?

Tags: python

I needed to sort a dict by value and then key, I surfed the net and found this >> [Sorting a dictionary by value then key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919342/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-key) << Someone answered and said "You need to take advantage of the fact that the values are numbers." and left a code

```
>>> [v[0] for v in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k))]
['peach', 'banana', 'beetroot', 'almond', 'apple']
```

What does -v mean? and what is the difference between v and -v ?

Comment: What's the difference between `1` and `-1`?

Comment: Simplified example, hope it helps: `sorted([1, 3, 2, 4], key=lambda x: x)`, `sorted([1, 3, 2, 4], key=lambda x: -x)`

Answer (score 1):

`x.items()` turns `Counter(...)` into a list of tuples: `[('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c': 7)]`. The `key` parameter says what value should be used to sort the list--and `k[1]` points to the second element of the `k` tuple.

And because the key is actually `-k[1]`, the resulting list is sorted in the reverse order, from the item with the biggest count to the one with the lowest count.

Comment: You mean the is no difference between this [v[0] for v in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k))]  and  [v[0] for v in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (v, k), reverse = True)]

Comment: If you're asking whether there's a difference between `key=lambda k: -k[1]` an `key=lambda k, v: (-v, k)` then yes, there is. In the first case only the count is used for sorting, whereas in the second case the string (name) is also used, in case the counts of two items are equal.