# Sort using values followed by keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a python dictionary as below:

```
wordCountMap = {'aaa':1, 'bbz':2, 'bbb':2, 'zzz':10}
```

I want to sort the dictionary such that it is the decreasing order of its values, followed by lexicographically increasing order for keys with same values.

```
result = {'zzz':10, 'bbb':2. 'bbz':2. 'aaa':1}
```

Here, 'bbb' is lexicographically smaller than 'bbz'. I know that in Python 2.x we could use a compare function. How do I do this in Python 3.x ?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to the sorted `list` by keying on the negation of the value, and the original key:

```
resultlist = sorted({'aaa':1, 'bbz':2, 'bbb':2, 'zzz':10}.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

If it must be converted back to a `dict`, just wrap that in the `dict` constructor:

```
resultdict = dict(sorted({'aaa':1, 'bbz':2, 'bbb':2, 'zzz':10}.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))
```

You could also do the work in two steps to simplify the `key` function; first sort without a `key` (which will sort on the keys of the `dict`):

```
sortedlist = sorted({'aaa':1, 'bbz':2, 'bbb':2, 'zzz':10}.items())
```

then sort by the values only (since Python's sort is stable, the key order will remain the same when the values are the same).

```
import operator  # At top of script

sortedlist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

then convert to a `dict`:

```
result = dict(sortedlist)
```

This *probably* won't be any faster (since it has to sort twice), but it does make each step simpler, and it works even when there is no reasonable way to "negate" the value being sorted (e.g. when the values are also strings).

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919342/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-key).

Assuming your dictionary is d, you can get it sorted with:

```
d = {'aaa':1, 'bbz':2, 'bbb':2, 'zzz':10}    
newD = [v[0] for v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0]))]
```

newD's value:

```
['zzz', 'bbb', 'bbz', 'aaa']
```

Comment: You copied more than you needed (the OP wants the keys and values in the result, not just the keys). Also, when the question is actually a duplicate, you can just flag it as such.