# How to sort python dictionary by value and key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to sort the dictionary by keys and values.

```
d = {'i': 1, 'live': 2, 'in': 2, 'bangalore': 2, 'is': 1, 'good': 1, 'city': 1, 'to': 1}
```

Output will be

```
{'bangalore': 2, 'in': 2, 'live': 2, 'city': 1, 'good': 1, 'i': 1, 'is': 1, 'to': 1}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a dictionary by value then key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919342/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-key)

Comment: @mikulatomas Marked duplicate asks for list as an output, OP wants a dict. 
OP, Please show us what you tried, SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

The linked question's answer can be adapted to your question:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))}
```

For your example

```
d = {'i': 1, 'live': 2, 'in': 2, 'bangalore': 2, 'is': 1, 'good': 1, 'city': 1, 'to': 1}
d = {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))}
print(d)
```

we get

```
{'bangalore': 2, 'in': 2, 'live': 2, 'city': 1, 'good': 1, 'i': 1, 'is': 1, 'to': 1}
```

as requested.

Answer (score 0):

sorting by key, then value is a simple sort operation on items:

```
d = dict(sorted(d.items()))

print(d)
{'bangalore': 2, 'city': 1, 'good': 1, 'i': 1, 'in': 2, 
 'is': 1, 'live': 2, 'to': 1}
```

To sort first on value then key, you can use the reversed tuples from the dictionary's `items()` as your sort key:

```
d = dict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda kv:kv[::-1]))

print(d)
{'city': 1, 'good': 1, 'i': 1, 'is': 1, 'to': 1, 
 'bangalore': 2, 'in': 2, 'live': 2}
```