# How to sort by the first letter of the key and then by the value in a dictionary

Tags: python

Here's my dictionary that maps countries to their populations

```
countryPop = {'China': 1402112, 'United States': 331449, 'India': 1380004, 'France': 67399,
                  'Britain': 67216, 'Ukraine': 41588, 'Canada': 38005, 'Russia': 147500,
                  'Germany': 83100, 'Italy': 59554}
```

This is the code to sort by key

```
 # Display the final dict once the user exits the loop
 for name, population in sorted(countryPop.items()):  # sorted the dict
     print('Country ', name, ' has population ', population, 'in thousands')
```

How could I list all countries in order of the first letter of the country name, sorted by the population?
For example, now my output have something like this

```
...
Country  Canada  has population  38005 in thousands
Country  China  has population  1402112 in thousands
...
```

China should go before Canada because it has more population (sort by value)

Comment: This question might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919342/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `key` parameter to `sorted()`:

```py
for name, population in sorted(countryPop.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0][0], -x[1])):
    print('Country ', name, ' has population ', population, 'in thousands')
```

This will use tuple comparison, comparing items based on the first letter of the key, and then using the value multiplied by `-1` as a tiebreaker (since we want to sort by population in descending order).

This outputs:

```
Country  Britain  has population  67216 in thousands
Country  China  has population  1402112 in thousands
Country  Canada  has population  38005 in thousands
Country  France  has population  67399 in thousands
Country  Germany  has population  83100 in thousands
Country  India  has population  1380004 in thousands
Country  Italy  has population  59554 in thousands
Country  Russia  has population  147500 in thousands
Country  United States  has population  331449 in thousands
Country  Ukraine  has population  41588 in thousands
```

Comment: I tried it but it still gave me the same output as the one I had, could you check the code, please?

Comment: I just edited it, try now.

Comment: Great it works, thank you! But is it possible to achieve the same output without using lambda?

Comment: You could define a function using the `def` keyword (as you would with any other function) and then pass that function into the `key` parameter. But in terms of conciseness, I don't think you can beat this. And while you're here, remember to upvote useful answers and accept the one you find most helpful. :)

Answer (score -1):

You will have to convert to a list and sort the list:

```
allx = list(countryPop.items())
allx.sort( key=lambda x: (x[0][1],x[1]) )
```

Note that the sort key is the first letter of the name, and the population.

Comment: If I print `àllx`, I get something that starts with `('Canada', 38005)` instead of `('Britain', 67216)`. You probably forgot to add `dict(allx)`. Please check the code once!

Comment: There's no need for `dict(allx)`, it's just that the key should be `x[0][0]` instead of `x[0][1]`.

Answer (score -1):

One way I have in mind is using `pandas`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(countryPop.items(), columns = ["key", "value"])
df = df.sort_values(by = list(df.columns))
dict(df.values)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this might still not resolve my problem, because only keys (the countries) are sorted, but I would like to sort by population after sorted by keys.

Comment: I just had a weird realization. Aren't dictionaries already sorted? If you print `countryPop` you would see that they are already sorted according to the key names.

Comment: yes they are already sorted by key names, but I would like it to sort by values after being sorted by keys (if some keys have the same letters, the largest population go first)

Comment: I've updated the answers, it would first sort the data by the keys, then the values.