# Sorting a dictionary by key and primarily the value

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

Im trying to implement a program which searches for bottlenecks in a network of roads.
My question:
I need to sort a dictionary by firstly the values and secondly the keys. The keys are house numbers and the values are number of bottlenecks. I want to sort the list by number of bottlenecks and if the value is equal decreasing by house number.

My dictionary looks like: dictionary = {3:5, 2:1, 5:1, 4:6} {house:bottlenecks}.
The sorted list would look like {4:6, 3:5, 5:1, 2:1}.

```
dictionary = {3:5, 2:1, 5:1, 4:6}

sort_dic = {i:dictionary[i] for i in range(max(dictionary_keys),0,-1) if i in dictionary.keys()}
first_key = list(sort_dic)
first_val = list(sort_dic.values())
sort_final = {first_val.index(i):i for i in range(max(first_val),0,-1) if i in first_val}
```

I'm trying to sort the keys first. Then just sort for the values.

It returns:

```
{1: 6, 2: 5, 0: 1}
```

The values are sorted right, but it skips keys and finds new keys like the 0 which shouldn't exist in this dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a dictionary by value then key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919342/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-key)

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use `sorted` to sort all the key-value pairs of the dict, then convert it back to a dict.

```py
res = dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], -x[0])))
# alternatively:
res = dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True))
```